# How to wait for the first function to finish executing before the second is executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, youtube-api, jquery-deferred

I'm trying to figure out a way to wait until the first function (`relatedVids(...)`) to finish executing and then in turn execute the second function (`relatedVidsDetails()`). What the code does is simply loop through a single `$.get(...)` request from the youtube api and loop through each of its item retrieved.

The problem with this as tested in the debugger, is that it will go in the first function (up to the `$.get()` without actually getting anything yet) then skip into the second function (once again, up to the `$.get()`). Then, it will proceed to execute the first function till it's finished retrieving all items, then when it gets into the second function, it will do the same thing but for some mysterious reason, the `videoIdChainStr` which holds all the video ids in a string from the first function is never retrieved or being executed since I suspected it executed the second function's `$.get(...)` already and never did it again a "second time" when it had the values.

So, my next step is trying to use `$.Deferred()` which is said to help resolve the first function first before even stepping into executing the second function so it will guaranteed values from the first function to be used in the second without skipping anything. But I'm not sure if I'm doing this right as it still does the same thing with or without using `$.Deferred()`.

**First function (relatedVids(...)):**

```
var relatedVidsDefer = function relatedVids(videoId)
{
var r = $.Deferred();

$.get( // get related videos related to videoId
    "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search",
    {
        part: 'snippet',
        maxResults: vidResults,
        relatedToVideoId: videoId,
        order: 'relevance',
        type: 'video',
        key: 'XXXXXXXXXX'
    },

    function(data)
    {
        debugger;
        $.each(data.items,
            function(i, item)
            {
                try
                {
                    console.log(item);
                    var vidTitle = item.snippet.title; // video title
                    var vidThumbUrl = item.snippet.thumbnails.default.url; // video thumbnail url
                    var channelTitle = item.snippet.channelTitle; // channel of uploaded video
                    var extractVideoId = null; // var to extract video id string from vidThumbUrl

                    // check if vidThumbUrl is not null, empty string, or undefined
                    if(vidThumbUrl)
                    {
                        var split = vidThumbUrl.split("/"); // split string when '/' seen
                        extractVideoId = split[4]; // retrieve the fourth index on the fourth '/'
                    }
                    else console.error("vidThumbUrl is either undefined or null or empty string.");
                    // if video title is longer than 25 characters, insert the three-dotted ellipse
                    if(vidTitle.length > 25)
                    {
                        var strNewVidTitle = vidTitle.substr(0, 25) + "...";
                        vidTitle = strNewVidTitle;
                    }

                    // check whether channelTitle is March of Dimes
                    if(channelTitle === "March of Dimes")
                    {
                        extractedVideoIdArr.push(extractVideoId); // add the extracted video id to the array

                        // check if extractedVideoIdArr is not empty
                        if(extractedVideoIdArr !== 'undefined' && extractedVideoIdArr.length > 0)
                        {
                            console.log("before join(): ", extractedVideoIdArr);
                            videoIdChainStr = extractedVideoIdArr.join(", "); // change from an array to a chain string of videoIds for the relatedVidsDetails() 
                            console.log("after join(): ", videoIdChainStr);
                        }

                        var vidThumbnail = '<div class="video-thumbnail"><a class="thumb-link" href="single-video.html"><div class="video-overlay"><img src="imgs/video-play-button.png"/></div><img src="' + vidThumbUrl + '" alt="No Image Available." style="width:204px;height:128px"/></a><p><a class="thumb-link" href="single-video.html">' + vidTitle + '</a><br/></div>'; //+ convert_time(vidDuration) + ' / Views: ' + viewCount + '</p></div>';

                        // print results
                        $('.thumb-related').append(vidThumbnail);
                        $(item).show(); // show current video thumbnail item 
                    }
                    else $(item).hide(); // hide current video thumbnail item
                }
                catch(err)
                {
                    console.error(err.message); // log error but continue operation    
                }
            } 
        ); 
    } 
);
return r;
};
```

**Second function (relatedVidsDetails(...)):**

```
var relatedVidsDetailsDefer = function relatedVidsDetails()
{
// change extractvideoid into a string by tostring() or join() for param to recognize
console.log("initial: ", extractedVideoIdArr);
$.get(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos",
    {
        part: 'snippet, contentDetails, statistics',
        id: videoIdChainStr, // chain string of video ids to be called upon in a single request
        key: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
    },

    function(data)
    {
        debugger;
        $.each(data.items,
            function(i, item)
            {
                try
                {
                    console.log("relatedVidsDetails()", item);
                    console.log("extractedvideoidarr: ", extractedVideoIdArr[i]);
                    var _vidDuration = item.contentDetails.duration;
                    var _viewCount = item.statistics.viewCount;
                    console.log("id: " + extractedVideoIdArr[i] + " duration: " + _vidDuration);
                    console.log("id: " + extractedVideoIdArr[i] + " viewCount: " + _viewCount);


                }
                catch(err)
                {
                    console.error(err.message); // log error but continue operation    
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
};
```

**Code being skipped when the second function has been tapped into the second time:**

```
$.each(data.items,
    function(i, item)
    {
       try
       {
           console.log("relatedVidsDetails()", item);
           console.log("extractedvideoidarr: ", extractedVideoIdArr[i]);
           var _vidDuration = item.contentDetails.duration;
           var _viewCount = item.statistics.viewCount;
           console.log("id: " + extractedVideoIdArr[i] + " duration: " + _vidDuration);
           console.log("id: " + extractedVideoIdArr[i] + " viewCount: " + _viewCount);
        }
        catch(err)
        {
           console.error(err.message); // log error but continue operation    
        }
     }
 );
```

The code being skipped due to the second function being stepped into when `videoIdChainStr` was empty and then skipped when first function completed and had the values ready for the second to use. I couldn't get this `videoIdChainStr` when it has values to then execute.

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer to the question: "How to wait for the first function to finish executing before the second is executed" would be:

USE CALLBACK OR PROMISES.

Example:

```
        function firstMethod() {
            // half of first method actions ...
            secondMethod(function() {
                // other half of first method actions
            });
        }

        function secondMethod(callBack) {
            // Second method actions
            setTimeout(function() { // The timeout is just a way to simulate the time that a response make us wait
                callBack();
            }, 5000);               
        }
```

Comment: How would I use promises in this case?